# Can I prevent keyboard input from being used by console?

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, console

I have a linux box with two keyboards, two displays, and one mouse. One of the displays is running an X session, and the other is running a text console, started by mingetty. Currently, the mouse is used by X, one of the keyboards is used only by the text console, but the other keyboard sends input to both the X session and the text console.

Is there any way to have the second keyboard send input to only the X session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is probably to write an `xorg.conf` and configure the "other keyboard" with option `GrabDevice` as `true`. This will make sure the kernel input layer only outputs events from this device to X, which means the console won't see them.

You can test the effect of the grab with `evtest --grab /dev/input/...` (which will make `evtest` grab it, of course).

See `man evdev` for details, see `Inputclass` and `Inputdevice` in `man xorg.conf` on how to match your keyboard using hardware ids (or google, there are plenty of tutorials).

Comment: FYI this no longer works if you're using the default `libinput` driver.  This is because an exclusive grab was found to prevent other users of the events (e.g. rfkill switches and the magic SysRq key) from working.  You won't get an error if you set `GrabDevice`, it will just be silently ignored. [Source](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2020-June/060305.html)