# Make the TTY console ignore the /dev/input/event3 keyboard

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, udev, tty

I have a remote control IR USB receiver, but it acts just like a normal keyboard.
I'm reading the input from `/dev/input/event3` to handle events. Because of this I need a way for the TTY console to ignore this "keyboard" device without disabling the USB device entirely.

So currently when I press buttons on the remote control it types characters into the TTY console, which is undesirable.

Comment: In X11 you can use `xinput` to disable input devices.

Comment: `evtest --grab /dev/input/event3` will show the events and not allow others to see them. Add the ioctl EVIOCGRAB to your reading code.

Comment: BTW, that exact same question has been asked either here or on superuser not so long ago.

Comment: Was it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388733/, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451370/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381944/ , or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343305/ ?