# Redirect all keyboard input to a detached screen session

Tags: raspberry-pi, gnu-screen, raspbian, framebuffer, headless

I'm trying to build a headless system using a Raspberry Pi; I have two programs runnning on it, one to catch all the input from a barcode reader (a simple keyboard emulation device) and one to display some graphics on a hdmi lcd screen using just the framebuffer (no X or DM envolved).
The reader program reads the input from the **stdin**; it is basically a **scanf** cycle that reads chars and doesn't print anything.
The barcorde reader prints there its chars and the reader program reads them until the "\n" char.
The display program embeds an http server that wait some request and paint the graphics on the framebuffer.
I run my two programs in two different `screen` sessions using:

```
screen -DmS reader ./reader_server &
S1=$!
screen -DmS graphics ./graphics_server &
S2=$!
wait $S1 $S2
```

I use two different screen sessions in the hope that the reading printed by the barcode reader and readed by the reader program doesn't interfere with the display session.
Everything works fine, both programs start on boot, the reader program awaits in its own session and the graphics program draw its stuff over the local tty...
The problem is that when I try to read some barcode the input is printed on the local tty, breaking my graphics and popping-up console pieces throught of it!
My question is: is there a way to send/redirect every keyboard input to my `screen` session where my reader program wait for it?

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understood your problem. Please [edit] your question and add more details what the programs `reader_server` and `graphics_server` do. Why do you need two `screen` sessions? If `reader_server` writes the data to `stdout` and `graphics_server` displays the data from `stdin` you could do something like `reader_server | graphics_server` in a script and run this script in the background (or in a `screen` session if you need this).

Comment: if you do not what the barcode typed on an emulated keyboard, then why do you use a keyboard emulator in the first place? Sounds strange ...
There is a pretty neat system for dealing with  inputs from multiple devices and writing to different visible and invisible outputs and organizing the whole stuff into neatly isolated sessions. It's called X. Maybe you want to give it a try.

Comment: @Bodo edited as you asked.

Comment: Can the barcode reader work in a different mode? (other than keyboard emulation)

Comment: No... only in keyboard emulation mode!

Comment: See [this related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482553/make-the-tty-console-ignore-the-dev-input-event3-keyboard) and especially the questions linked in its comments. You will probably have to base your solutio on `evtest`